# Parsing RTSP stream for live radio

Tags: java, http, audio-streaming, rtsp, internet-radio

I want to be able to parse the rtsp stream in order to extract data about the radio station, current playing song name, duration etc.

I have to do it manually - no libraries.

Preferred language is Java but I could work with something else too.

Comment: Check this link http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/38120/Parser.java__html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [RFC 2326: Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt).

You'll need to become a bit of an expert in the higher level structures and then code your own parser to extract the meta data.

You'd really save a lot of time by using a library.  You should reconsider that decision.

Comment: thanks I came to this conclusion too. It would be good to make use of a library but there isn't afaik for blackberry.